# Implicit serializing case class to Json with play.api.libs.json

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework, format

This is my case class Response api model that must be transformed to json(Play 2.5):

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

case class ResponseModel(content: NestedCaseClassModel)

object ResponseModel {
  implicit val format: OFormat[ResponseModel] = Json.format
}

case class NestedCaseClassModel(value: String)

object NestedCaseClassModel {
  implicit val format: OFormat[NestedCaseClassModel] = Json.format
}
```

**The problem is:** 
When I have very deeply nested response structure, I need implement companion object for each case class in my model, and add *implicit format*, that looking very similar.

I looking for a mechanism that permit to me write it one time and use it for any case class. I can't switch form play.api.libs.json library.

Any idea about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to tell you how to do what you want to do, and then I'm going to tell you why you shouldn't do that.

If you want a format automatically generated for you, then you just need to implement an implicit macro. We need to differentiate which types we want to have a format automatically generated for, if you just make it for `Any`, then it will override things like `String` which would be bad. So, we'll define a trait that all our case classes will implement:

```
trait ImplicitJsonFormat
```

And now we implement our implicit macro for it:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.language.experimental.macros

trait JsonImplicits {
  // This works for Play 2.5, in Play 2.6 it becomes JsMacroImpl.implicitConfigFormatImpl
  implicit def implicitJsonFormat[A <: ImplicitJsonFormat]: OFormat[A] = macro JsMacroImpl.formatImpl[A]
}
```

And so now anything that you want a format automatically generated for, you just need to extends `ImplicitJsonFormat`, and ensure whatever needs the implicit format has had `JsonImplicits` mixed in:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}

case class ResponseModel(content: NestedCaseClassModel)

object ResponseModel extends JsonImplicits {
  implicit val format: OFormat[ResponseModel] = Json.format
}

case class NestedCaseClassModel(value: String) extends ImplicitJsonFormat
```

And there you have it, `NestedCaseClassModel` has its format automatically generated. Of course, you could also automatically generate the format for `ResponseModel` too.

But you really shouldn't do this. Why? Sometimes being explicit has value. These json structures aren't just incidental things with no relevance. They form the protocol of your REST API, or the protocol of whatever you're using. That's generally something that you want to be explicit about, and consistent throughout your code base. By explicitly defining the format on each companion type, you have this consistent place to go and look to for what the format is. And when you need to customise it, you can replace your macro with a manual format declaration, and you haven't changed anything about your approach to declaring the formats, the answer still lies in go and look at the format field on the companion object.

Sure, when you create a project up front, declaring all these formats may be a little tedious. But it's one of those things that's simple to do, easy to get right, and once it's done it's done. As your codebase evolves and progresses, you're probably going to have other things in the companion objects anyway, and you will find yourself needing to evolve the formats, and move away from the macros as you migrate your codebase and the schema of your protocol in different directions.

Comment: The approach taken in https://gitlab.com/fommil/stalactite is a proven middle ground between explicit and boilerplate, being what Haskell does.